# When using mapper from Jackson to convert my response to List<Object>, get an error

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Right now, I have a method in

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<List<T>> getProduct(String resource, Map<String, String> queryParams)
      throws Exception {
   return getRestTemplate().exchange(endpointAddress + resource, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity(createHeaders()),
         new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>(){}, queryParams);
}
```

When I call this method as `ResponseEntity<List<Product>> myProduct = myServer.getProduct("someURL", myQuery)` in my Adapter class, It works fine. If I `LOG.debug()` the `response.getBody().toString()` I get something like `<200,[{name="Terry", ID=4234, City="Dallas"}]>`
My `Product` class has methods such as `getName()` and `getID()`. I cannot simply do `response.getBody().get(0).getID()` as Jackson doesn't know the type of object I'm using. I've tried doing:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Product> product = mapper.convertValue(response.getBody(), new TypeReference<List<Product>>() {});
```

But that errors out to. On the otherhand, I can convert the body to a json

```
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(wlsProduct.getBody().get(0));
```

and parse it to get the response, but I'd much rather use the methods within the `Product` class. Is there an alternative solution or something I'm missing?

Edit: The error I get is `java.lang.ClassCastException`

Answer (score 0):

`myServer.getProduct("someURL", myQuery)` does not return a list of `Product`s, but a list of `LinkedHashMap`s. You probably get a `java.lang.ClassCastException` (next time you should specify the exception in your question, so we do not have to make assumptions).

your code should work as expected once you change the `getProduct` method like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getProduct(String resource, Map<String, String> queryParams)
    throws Exception {
    return getRestTemplate().exchange(endpointAddress + resource, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity(createHeaders()),
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Product>>(){}, queryParams);
}
```

why generics? your `getProduct()` seems to be specific to `Produt` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your body looks like `<200,[valid JSON content]>` so remove from your body "200," at hte beginning and ">" at the end and you should be fine

to read from Json String to Object do this:

```
data = objectReader.forType(type).readValue(jsonString);
```

Where data is an instance of your class - `Product` and type is an instance of the class. I guess it would be `Product.class`. But with the list it is a bit problematic. You can read your Json as a `List<Map>>` and then run over the list and convert each map into your Person instance

Comment: When I do ```response.getBody()``` that retrieves the JSON content. But I want it as a ```Product``` type